# Writing a whole list in a CSV row-Python/IronPython

Tags: python, csv, ironpython

Right now I have several  long lists : One called variable_names.

Lets say Variable names= [ Velocity, Density, Pressure, ....] (length is 50+)

I want to  write a row that reads every  index of the list, leaves about 5 empty cells, then writes next value, and keeps doing it until list is done.

As shown in  row1 Sample picture

[image: Sample Output]

The thing is I can't use xlrd due to compatibility issues with Iron Python and I need to dynamically write each row in the new csv , load data from old csv , then append that data in the new csv, the old csv keeps changing once I append the data in the new csv, so I need to iterate all values in the lists for every time I write the row, because it is much more difficult to append columns in csv.

What I basicall want to do is :

```
 with open('data.csv','a') as f:
     sWriter=csv.writer(f)
     sWriter.writerow([Value_list[i],Value_list[i+1],Value_list[i+2].....Value_list[end])
```

But I can't seem to think of a way to do this with iteration

Comment: How about use a iteration to generate the list then write with `writerow` method?

Comment: The list is already generated, when I use iteration  with the writerow method, I get each index in a different row, rather than having them in a different column

Comment: That must be and you've misunderstood me. Let me explain in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `writerow` method takes a `list` argument, you can first construct the list and then write the list so everything in the list will be in one row.

Like,

```
with open('data.csv','a') as f:
     sWriter=csv.writer(f)
     listOfColumns = []
     for i in range(from, to): # append elements from Value_list
          listOfColumns.append(Value_list[i])
     for i in range(0, 2): # Or you may want some columns with blank
          listOfColumns.append("")
     for i in range(anotherFrom, anotherTo): # append elements from Value_list
          listOfColumns.append(Value_list[i])
     # At here, the listOfColumns will be [Value_list[from], ..., Value_list[to], "", "", Value_list[anotherFrom], ..., Value_list[anotherTo]]
     sWriter.writerow(listOfColumns)
```

Comment: It works!! but is there a better way to append spaces between the index assuming I have 50+ variables I need to append spaces in between?

Comment: actually I figured it out, but thank you your ideas helped

Comment: @pcftgeorge That's quite a lot of code for essentially `sWriter.writerow(Value_list[from:to] + [''] * 2 + Value_list[anotherFrom:anotherTo])`.

Comment: @BlackJack yeah, i just wanted to demonstrate explicitly  how it works and how flexible it can be. If you are familiar with Python, you can easily make it simpler.